# ubuntu server git Connection timed out

Tags: git, ubuntu

On ubuntu server, git clone doesn't work

```
panda@gitlab:~$ git clone https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq.git
Cloning into 'gitlabhq'...
error: Failed connect to github.com:443; Connection timed out while accessing https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq.git/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack
fatal: HTTP request failed
```

But it work on win7 pc in same network

What i should check?

Answer (score 0):

> I think your **`.netrc`** is incorrect or something worng in that?
>   Try removing the info from your `.netrc` and add again  (since it's a public repo).
>
> If it isn't a **`.netrc`** issue, it could be your **firewall or
>   proxy** (`git config --global http.proxy http://user:password@proxy:xxx`).

Comment: It isn't a .netrc issue and i haven't proxy in my network. And as i say, git work correct on win7 pc.